# how to iOS mosquitto in background

Tags: ios, swift, mosquitto

I have some problem for developing iOS app with libmosquitto

in my code
AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MosquittoClientDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?
    var client: MosquittoClient?

    func didPublish(messageId: UInt) {
        println( "didPublish \(messageId)" )
    }
    func didReceiveMessage(mosq_msg: MosquittoMessage!) {
        println( "didReceiveMessage [ \(mosq_msg.mid)-\(mosq_msg.topic) ] \(mosq_msg.payload)" )
    }
    func didDisconnect() {
        println( "didDisconnect" )
    }
    func didConnect(code: UInt) {
        println( "didConnect \(code)" )
        if code == UInt(MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS.value){
            client?.subscribe("sample", withQos: 1)
        }
    }
    func didSubscribe(messageId: UInt, grantedQos qos: [AnyObject]!) {
        println( "didSubscribe" )
    }
    func didUnsubscribe(messageId: UInt) {
        println( "didUnsubscribe \(messageId)" )
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
        client = MosquittoClient(clientId: "qq")
        client?.host = "stick.coffee"
        client?.port = 1883
        client?.delegate = self
        client?.connect()
        return true
    }
}
```

This working what i think except when app is exited.

I want receiveMessage even if app is exited.

and I founded there are some mode for background.

- Audio and AirPlay
- Location updates
- Voice over IP
- Newsstand downloads
- External accessory communication
- Uses Bluetooth LE accessories
- Acts as Bluetooth LE accessory
- Background fetch
- Remote Notification

what is best mode for me?
Or is there some example for this stub?

Comment: Not related to your Question, But can you suggest where can I get libmosquitto for iOS?
I downloaded the files and put in a folder but it did not has With_TLS flag in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep,
I found out there is no method for background running.

but voip can run in background if no need for uploading AppleStore.

so I implements with voip.